# Book or short story about two boys or men who fall down a hole into a cavern where dinosaurs roam

Tags: story-identification, books, dinosaurs

This might be a tricky one. It may be more of a short story. I only know the plot.

Two boys or maybe men are exploring near water in a jungle when a large predator cat scares them into a nearby cave. They fall down a hole in the cave and when landing at the bottom one boy receives a goose egg-sized welt on his head. They hide behind a boulder while dinosaurs roam around this weird prehistoric underground. The story ends with the conscious boy literally tearing his clothes and freehand scaling the hole all the way back up to the surface with the other boy still unconscious on his back.

I remember the story vividly and it may even be a short story. At one point, a dinosaur charges the boulder and the boy puts its horn in his pocket, only to have it turn to dust when he reaches the surface again.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.